# Precedence order in Ansible variable assignments, confused

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - vars/common_vars.yml
  vars:
    deploy_folder: "win"
```

in my vars/common_vars.yml

```
deploy_folder: "linux_deploy"
```

I expected to `vars:` in the playbook take precedence over `vars/files`, so I can override it. This is not the case, if I debug the variable I got the value "linux_deploy".

To make sure what is happening I renamed the variable in `common_vars.yml` to `linux_variable2` and changed nothing else, now the debug statement writes that the deploy_folder is "win". So it is proven, the variable assignment in `common_vars.yml` overtakes the vars: ...

I supposed the opposite. Anyway, I want to override the assignment in common_vars.yml in that playbook. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) answer your question?

Comment: ^- and so to override the variable, one of the possibility that have an higher precedence is using a `set_fact`.

Comment: Many thx for both of you, yes it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options for how to solve this problem.

- The simplest one is putting the file *common.yml* into the directory *group_vars/all/* ([precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) 5.)

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/common.yml 
deploy_folder: linux_deploy
test_folder: linux_test
devel_folder: linux_devel
```

Then, the below play

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    deploy_folder: win

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          deploy_folder: {{ deploy_folder }}
          devel_folder: {{ devel_folder }}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    deploy_folder: win
    devel_folder: linux_devel
```

---

- If you have to read the file from *vars* you can override the variables on your own. For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat vars/common.yml 
deploy_folder: linux_deploy
test_folder: linux_test
devel_folder: linux_devel
```

include the variables from the file into a dictionary, for example, *my_defaults*, and use it as defaults

```yaml
    - block:

        - include_vars:
            file: common.yml
            name: my_defaults

        - set_fact:
            deploy_folder: "{{ deploy_folder|d(my_defaults.deploy_folder) }}"
            test_folder: "{{ test_folder|d(my_defaults.test_folder) }}"
            devel_folder: "{{ devel_folder|d(my_defaults.devel_folder) }}"

      run_once: true
```

You can put the block into a file and import it into a playbook to minimize the code. Tag the import *always*.

```yaml
shell> cat include_vars.yml 
- include_vars:
    file: common.yml
    name: my_defaults

- set_fact:
    deploy_folder: "{{ deploy_folder|d(my_defaults.deploy_folder) }}"
    test_folder: "{{ test_folder|d(my_defaults.test_folder) }}"
    devel_folder: "{{ devel_folder|d(my_defaults.devel_folder) }}"
```

This is the most flexible option because any declaration of **_folder* overrides the default.

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    deploy_folder: win

  tasks:

    - import_tasks: include_vars.yml
      run_once: true
      tags: always

    - debug:
        msg: |
          deploy_folder: {{ deploy_folder }}
          devel_folder: {{ devel_folder }}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    deploy_folder: win
    devel_folder: linux_devel
```

- Create *include_vars.yml* automatically

```yaml
- name: Create include_vars.yml
  hosts: localhost

  vars:

    common_file: common.yml
    common_dict: my_defaults

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ common_file }}"
        name: "{{ common_dict }}"

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/include_vars.yml"
        content: |
          - include_vars:
              file: {{ common_file }}
              name: {{ common_dict }}
          - set_fact:
          {% for k in lookup('vars', common_dict).keys() %}
              {{ k }}: "{{ open }} {{ k }}|d({{ common_dict }}.{{ k }}) {{ close }}"
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        open: '{{ "{{" }}'
        close: '{{ "}}" }}'
```